# AngularJs listening changes of service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why in 1, 2, 3 cases changing message in service doesn't affect on displaed message ?

```
var app = angular.module('app', []); 

app.factory('Message', function() {
  return {message: "why this message doesn't changed"};
});

app.controller('Changer', function($scope, Message) {
  Message.message = "first" // (1)

  $scope.changeItems = function() {
    Message.message = "second" // (2)
  }
});

app.controller('Listener', function($scope, Message) {
  $scope.message = Message.message
  Message.message = "third" // (3)
});
```

And my view:

```
<div ng-controller="Listener">
  {{ message }}  
</div>

<div ng-controller="Changer">
  <button ng-click="changeItems()">change message</button>
</div>
```

I've also created example on plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/BUPS6U0S7ktDEkH9dZTZ?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is because the "Listener" controller get initiated first because it appears on the View's HTML first. If you switch the order you'll see the "First" message.

One more thing, when you set a reference to a string and later change the string, you lose the reference, that's why it's more powerful to refer to an object and then render the object's property like this:

Controller:

```
$scope.Message = Message
```

View:

```
{{Message.message}}
```

That way you don't lose the reference